# How to fill complex shapes within its border?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, xml

I just made this shape by combining a rectangle and numerous arcs together. I finally grouped them to create this one complex shape. The only trouble I'm having is filling the object. Whenever I try to fill it, this seems to happen.

The second below image is my end goal. I would appreciate any help.

[image]

[image: My end goal is this image:]

Comment: Please share the shape code. You probably have to use <fillstroke> instead of <stroke>.